# How to remove key value pair from map using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have to remove some key value pairs from a map if value of pair is "Bridgeport" :

```
let map = {
    "country":"US",
    "state": "CT",
    "town": "Bridgeport"         
}
```

and get:

```
alteredMap = {
    "country":"US",
    "state": "CT",       
}
```

The ['_.remove()'](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#remove) does not seem to work as it only works for arrays. Assume we don't know the keys of the map, how can we get to alteredMap if we want to remove values that equals to `Bridgeport`?

I was trying:

```
_.reduce(map, (value,key)=>{
    return value=='Bridgeport'
})
```

Comment: May I ask you why you're looking for a lodash solution? is it mandatory or is plain js accepted as well?

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried to remove?

Comment: You might want -> `_.omit`  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#omit

Comment: @StuiterSlurf I was doing: `_.reduce(map, (value,key)=>{
    return value=='Bridgeport'
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `omitBy` method that takes a callback with two `(value, key)` arguments and returns a new object. You could do the same with `pickBy` method just inverse the condition

```
_.pickBy(map, e => e != 'Bridgeport')
```

```js
let map = {"country": "US","state": "CT","town": "Bridgeport"}
const result = _.omitBy(map, e => e == 'Bridgeport')
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I have to remove some key value pairs from a map if value of pair is
>   "Bridgeport"

A vanilla js solution could be

- Find the key(s) with value `Bridgeport`
- Use `delete` to remove those *key value pairs* from the `map`

i.e.

```
var valueToFind = "Bridgeport";
Object.keys(map)
  .filter( s => map[s] == valueToFind ) //find keys with valueToFind 
  .forEach( s => delete map[s] ); //delete those keys
```

**Demo**

```js
let map = {
    "country":"US",
    "state": "CT",
    "town": "Bridgeport"         
};

var valueToFind = "Bridgeport";
    Object.keys(map)
      .filter( s => map[s] == valueToFind ) 
      .forEach( s => delete map[s] ); 
      
console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the object using `Object.keys` and then use `Array.reduce` method to filter out the desired value.

```js
let map = {
    "country":"US",
    "state": "CT",
    "town": "Bridgeport"         
};

var updatedMap = Object.keys(map).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (map[curr] === "Bridgeport") {
    return acc;
  }
  acc[curr] = map[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(updatedMap);
```